# onclick event is not working with option tag in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, onclick

I have a following html drop down menu with `Go` button, it is working fine for the first two option values selection first and then hitting `Go` button, but not working for other two option values, which are having onclick events, Please help me that how to work with onclick event in `<option>` tag so that I can execute respective alert messages. I need it should work in Google Chrome browser. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function third(){
alert("It is a third option event");
}
function fourth(){
alert("Fourth option value");
}
</script>
</head>
<form name="testform" id="testformid">
<select name="testdropdownmenu" >
<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
<option value="https://www.w3schools.com">First Option</option>
<option value="https://www.google.co.in">Second Option</option>
<option onclick="third()">Third Option</option>
<option onclick="fourth()">Fourth Option</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="go" value="Go" onClick="location=document.testform.testdropdownmenu.options
[document.testform.testdropdownmenu.selectedIndex].value;">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery

```js
$(function(){
  $('#testdropdownmenu').on('change', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val === 'third') {
    alert('third option') 
  }
  else if(val === 'fourth') {
    alert('fourth option') 
  }
  })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="testform" id="testformid">
<select name="testdropdownmenu" id="testdropdownmenu">
<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
<option value="https://www.w3schools.com">First Option</option>
<option value="https://www.google.co.in">Second Option</option>
<option value="third">Third Option</option>
<option value="fourth">Fourth Option</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="go" value="Go" onClick="location=document.testform.testdropdownmenu.options
[document.testform.testdropdownmenu.selectedIndex].value;">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```js
function checkval() {
  var val = document.getElementById('testdropdownmenu').value 
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
    <form name="testform" id="testformid">
    <select name="testdropdownmenu" id="testdropdownmenu"onchange="checkval()">
    <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
    <option value="https://www.w3schools.com">First Option</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.in">Second Option</option>
    <option value="third">Third Option</option>
    <option value="fourth">Fourth Option</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="go" value="Go" onClick="location=document.testform.testdropdownmenu.options
    [document.testform.testdropdownmenu.selectedIndex].value;">
    </form>
```

Use the onchange event on select and then compare its value.

Comment: thank you for your help, it is helped for my requirement.

Comment: is there any chance to do the same thing with AngularJS ng-change event ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot trigger "onclick" event for option tag. Instead You can use "onchange" event of select tag.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick attribute is not supported by the option tag. better use the onchange function on the 'select' tag

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

function changeValue() {
   //get selected value
}
</script>
</head>
<form name="testform" id="testformid">
<select name="testdropdownmenu" onchange="changeValue();" >
<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
<option value="https://www.w3schools.com">First Option</option>
<option value="https://www.google.co.in">Second Option</option>
<option >Third Option</option>
<option >Fourth Option</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="go" value="Go" onClick="location=document.testform.testdropdownmenu.options
[document.testform.testdropdownmenu.selectedIndex].value;">
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use onFocus, will trigger when user focus on the element

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` is not the appropriate event to attach on `select > option`

Instead you should use `onchange` for your case. `onchange` fires whenever you change the the value of select box. And then in your function called on click you can check if its second/third then do something. check the code below:

In HTML:

```
 <select id="testdropdownmenu" onchange="myFunction()">
```

And in Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var favValue = document.getElementById("testdropdownmenu").value;
    // Do something your favourite value appears here
    alert(favValue);
}
```

Hope this helps!!